# php calculate float

Tags: php, math, floating-point

I have a weird math calculation here.  I hope someone will explain.

```
$a = 1.85/100;
$b = 1.5/100;
$c = 1.1/100;
$d = 0.4/100;
$e = 0.4/100;
$f = 0.4/100;
$g = 0.4/100;

$h = $a + $b + $c + $d + $e + $f + $g;

echo $h*100 ."<br>";
$i = $h-$a;
$i = $i-$b;
$i = $i-$c;
$i = $i-$d;
$i = $i-$e;
$i = $i-$f;
$i = $i-$g;

echo $i;
```

The last `$i` value should be 0 but it returns 6.93889390391E-18.

Comment: That are the quirks of floating point arithmetics. Read http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: 0.004 - $g = 0; but 0.004 - $i = 6.93889390391E-18; any idea to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any idea to correct my equation to show final result 0.00 ?

Yeah, `round($i, 2)`

The "discrepancies" are usually so small, that rounding it to 2 decimals will almost always solve the problem.

Comment: use number_format() instead if you want to force it to display two decimals.

Comment: btw, I see that you're using up to 3 decimals in your calculations, so you should probably round it to 4 in case there's an actual discrepancy..

Comment: nice info.. is there any performance related problem between round and number_format?

Comment: no, they do the same thing, except number_format returns a string and round returns a float, which in php could be converted to an integer if there is no decimal value.

Comment: This does not work till end for negative outcome. .. Example `32560-(32.56*1000) = -3.6379788070917E-12` even if i do `round($value, 2)` it returns `-0`

Answer (score 6):

You should read this article:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Floating point arithmetic is not exact. You should expect small errors. The answer is correct to within a small rounding error. If you need to check if a floating point number is zero it is best not to check that it is exactly equal to zero but instead to check if it is sufficiently close to zero.

If you really need exact arithmetic, don't use floating point types. In your example you could multiply all your numbers by 100 and use integer arithmetic to get an exact answer.

Comment: wow so detail explaination. any idea to correct my equation to show final result 0.00 ?

Comment: Since all your numbers are rational you could do your calculations using rational numbers and get an exact result.

Comment: dead link, i believe it is now https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong going there, there are simply rounding approximation.

In this very cas you should multiply all your values for 1000 and do a division at the end of the calculation or, better, resort to [precise calculation extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Comment: nice info eineki. this will help me to be carefull for another calculation. thanks all for great help.