# Why does PHP calculate -2.27373675443E-13 for (89.99*12) - 1079.88?

Tags: php, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php calculate float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661817/php-calculate-float)
>   [The accuracy of PHP float calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957705/the-accuracy-of-php-float-calculate)

Why does PHP calculate -2.27373675443E-13 for this...

```
echo  (89.99*12) - 1079.88;
```

shouldn't it return 0?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) calculations are complicated and potentially inaccurate. this problem appears in every programming-language because decimal numbers can't be stored perfectly in binary representation.

to quote [PHPs documentation about this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> Warning
>   **Floating point precision**
>
> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. I solved the issue with: echo  round(89.99*12,2) - 1079.88;